# Get amount of unique elements in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, unique

I have an array
`arr = np.array([[1,1,2], [1,2,3]])`.
I want to get amount of unique element for each row and count mean
I can do this `np.array([len(np.unique(row)) for row in arr]).mean()`.
But seems, that it's a slow way. Is there another faster approach?

Comment: Since `unique` will return a different length array for each row, this probably is the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]])


mean = np.apply_along_axis(lambda row: len(set(row)), axis=1, arr=arr).mean()
```

```
>> mean = 2.5
```

Comment: `apply...` is usually slower than a simple loop.

Answer (score 0):

`set(arr.flatten())` will create your desired result. Not sure about how fast it is though.

Output:
`{1, 2, 3}`

Edit:
You wanted the number of unique elements, so you wrap the whole thing in `len()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that, up to my knowledge, is the fastest.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Number of unique elements row wise then mean
def unique(x):
    df = pd.DataFrame(x.T)
    return df.nunique().mean()

arr = np.array([[1,1,2], [1,2,3]])

print(unique(arr))
```

Output:

```
2.5
```

Comment: maybe reconsider remaning your function? It could be confusing with the package called `pandas`?

Comment: @BrunoLubascher that is done, thanks.

Comment: It's much slower approach on big matrixes